# MongoDB operations on embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

Given the document below within the *marketlist* collection:

```
{
  "_id": OjectId(...),
  "user": 'myName',
  "marketList: [
    {
      "marketName": "Ralphs",
      "shoppingList: [
        { itemName: "cookies", isCrossed: false },
        { itemName: "bananas", isCrossed: true }
      ]   
    }
  ]
}
```

How do you:
1) $pull market out of the marketList?
The following matches the document, but does not modify anything:

```
db.marketlist.update(
{
  user: 'myName'
},
{ $pull: { marketList: {marketName: 'Ralphs'}}})
```

2) $pull a single item out of the shoppingList (without pulling the entire market document out)
The following has no effect whatsoever, not even a return message on the command line

```
db.marketlist.update(
{
  user: 'myName'
},
{$pull: {marketList: {shoppingList: { itemName: 'cookies'}}}})
```

According to mongoDB documentation on the $pull operator, the solution proposed in #1 should do the job.
As for #2, I am completely lost. Any insights into what I am doing wrong in either case are very much appreciated.

Comment: In Brief, don't nest arrays.The [documentation for the positional  $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays) makes note of this. Now you know the topic, you can also search for the terms ["mongodb nested array update"](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+nested+array+update). So what you really should do is alter your document structure to remove the nesting of arrays.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction @NeilLunn. It seems mongo falls short with nested arrays as their positional operator is only good for 1 level. I've reformatted my structure to a more mongo-friendly layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since mongodb's positional operator does cannot represent more than 1 matched element, you need to restructure the way you store your data in a way that does not nest arrays. One potential solution is to nest objects instead:

```
{
  "_id": OjectId(...),
  "user": 'myName',
  "marketList: [
    {
      "marketName": "Ralphs",
      "shoppingList:{
        "cookie": { itemName: "cookies", isCrossed: false },
        "bananas": { itemName: "bananas", isCrossed: true }
      }   
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
{
user: 'myName'
},
{$pull: {'marketList.0.shoppingList': { "itemName": 'cookies'}}})
```

This will pull a single item out of the shoppingList with match on the field itemName with the value we specify ("cookies" in this case)